# "Target Framework" compatibility

Tags: vb.net

I am having a problem. The following code should output a single line describing my local instance of SQL. After lots of poking and prodding I have found that the code succeeds when it is compiled with the "Target Framework" set to v3.5, but it fails to return any instances when the "Target Framework" is set to anything higher. There is no error, exception, warning or other explanation. I know that it is not simply taking longer to find the instance because it reaches the final "Console.Readkey()" within .04 seconds when the target is v3.5.

I suppose what I really want to know is: How can I make this work without changing the Target Framework? I would rather not if I don't have to since I have written the rest of my project under the default (v4.5.2) and don't know what consequences might arise from doing so.

P.S. Bonus points if you can tell me why this doesn't work after v3.5.

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim datatable As DataTable = System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()

    For Each row As DataRow In datatable.Rows

        For i As Integer = 0 To (datatable.Columns.Count - 1)
            Console.Write(row.Item(i) & vbTab)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next

    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Which version of Windows are you running on?

Comment: Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you appear to be experiencing this [reported bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1633740/system-data-sql-sqldatasourceenumerator-doesnt-work-on-windows-10-with-net-framework-4-x).

If it looks like the bug report matches your problem, consider voting to have it fixed.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds like my issue exactly. What are the odds?